# How does one select all text in a Windows Forms TextBox?

Tags: c#, textbox

How do I allow select all in my multi-lined TextBox?

It seems weird to me that there would not be a way to do this; there should be something in the framework out of the box.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In case of [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms):

```
textbox.SelectAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the SelectAll method (actually located on TextBoxBase).

```
TextBoxBase b = GetTheTextBox();
b.SelectAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `textbox1.SelectAll()`?

You can also use

```
textbox1..Select(0, textbox1.Text.Length);
```

and turn property **HideSelection** to ***False***.